# unique validation is in not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am making a todo list with validation using laravel 5.4.

When I click on the submit button, only the required validation is working but not the unique.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it so as to get it working as desired?

Below is my form (located at `home.blade.php`):

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form form-control" action="/todo" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="textbox" id="textArea"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    {{-- for dispaying the error --}}
    @if (count($errors) >0)
        {{-- expr --}}
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <h3 class="text-danger">{{$error}}</h3>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

Here, the content of my Todo controller (in my `todocontroller.php` file):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\todo;
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $todo = new todo;
    $todo->body = $request->textbox;
    $this->validate($request,[
        "body" => "required|unique:todos"
    ]);
    $todo->save();
    return redirect('/todo');
}
```

Comment: What is not working about the unique? Does it always throw an error or never?

Comment: directly pass "textbox" instead of body like wise.
$this->validate($request,["textbox" => "required|unique:todos"]);

Comment: Is your question solved? Are you still facing any challenge?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use the name of the field; you don't need to stress yourself.

Take a look at the snippet below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Todo;// following Laravel's standards, your model name should be Todo; not todo
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NameOfYourTodoController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $todo = new Todo();

        // use the name of the field directly (here, textbox)
        $this->validate($request, [
            'textbox' => 'required|unique:todos'
        ]);

        // other code logics here.
    }
}
```